# How can I provide a default implementation for an overridable method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, overriding, abstract-class

I am playing around with the Visitor pattern, and I have the following bit of code which compiles:

```
class DerivedVisitee;

class Visitor
{
public:
    void visit(DerivedVisitee &v);
};

class Visitee
{
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor &v) = 0;
};

class DerivedVisitee : public Visitee
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); }
};
```

I would like to provide a default `visit` method for all descendants of `Visitee`. As such, I tried to do the following:

```
class DerivedVisitee;

class Visitor
{
public:
    void visit(DerivedVisitee &v);
};

class Visitee
{
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor &v) { v.visit(*this); } // added implementation here
};

class DerivedVisitee : public Visitee
{
    // removed overridden method
};
```

But compilation fails with `'void Visitor::visit(DerivedVisitee &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'Visitee' to 'DerivedVisitee &'` (MSVC). Can you explain why this happens, and what is a correct method for doing what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT:** `Visitor::visit` needs to work on `DerivedVisitee` objects only; to put it another way, I intend to use multiple overloaded `Visitor::visit` methods with different implementations, for different descendants of `Visitee`.

Comment: [OT]: You may add a virtual destructor to `Visitee`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120627/default-implementation-of-an-interface-that-is-used-as-a-contained-component

Comment: @Peladao: languages tend to have their own specific answers to the problem.

Comment: This isn't really a question about the visitor design pattern (you seem to have that down). It seems more a question of syntactic implementation in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is: *you cannot* in pure object oriented code.

By nature the Visitor pattern is about passing to `visit` the derived type, and in `Visitee` said type is unknown (it's a runtime property).

---

In C++, there exists a pattern called [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
class VisiteeHelper: public Base {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor& v) override {
        Derived& d = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
        v.visit(d);
}; // class VisiteeHelper
```

and then you can derive from this:

```
// And there we see the "Curiously Recurring" part:
class DerivedVisitee: public VisiteeHelper<DerivedVisitee, Visitee> {
}; // class DerivedVisitee

class MoreDerivedVisitee: public VisiteeHelper<MoreDerivedVisitee, DerivedVisitee> {
}; // MoreDerivedVisitee
```

It's up to you to decide whether you prefer the dead-simple boilerplate or the smart (but potentially confusing) CRTP solution.

Personally, unless you have multiple overloads of `accept` (up to 4 per type by overloading on const-ness), I would not bother. It's about as much work to write the `accept` by hand, and it's dead simple, and immediately understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `Visitee&` instead of `DerivedVisitee&` as argument of `visit` method. This is the whole point of using **public inheritance** and **Polymorphism**. Any *derived* object can be used where a *base* object is expected. At runtime, the actual type will be deducted and appropriate method will be called on that object.

Comment: I made an edit which explains why this is not an option, thanks.

Comment: @DanNestor, if only derived will be used, then why do you need a default method in the first place? Default is for base, which can not be used, seems weird.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: You don't know the visitor pattern do you ?

Comment: @RakibulHasan - `Visitor::visit` will have different implementations, but `Visitee::accept` will be the same for most of the descendants of `Visitee`.